Navigation component, Fragments and predictive back: some clarification
I'm trying to implement the predictive back gesture in an app based over fragments and navigation component. While it works out of the box for bottom sheets and activities, it doesn't work with fragments.
To be precise, it works using this approach (bottom of this page, based on this example) but, as the page says, This is a "non-native" approach and still the user can't see the previous fragment when swiping back. Is there a way to have a better result? Here's what I currently have:

